# Group values and sum keys in flat, associative array

Tags: php, arrays, sum, grouping

Please help needed to solve output as array key sum and value by group.

My actual output :

```
$array = array(
    '7'=>'15',
    '20'=>'6',
    '11'=>'9',
    '14'=>'6',
    '4'=>'15'
 );
```

I need final array to sum of keys and group by value like :

```
$array = array('15' => 11, '6' => 34, '9' => 11);
```

Comment: Where is the `'4'=>'20'` coming from? Seems like it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We expect you to show what you have already tried first of all. This is not a code-writing service where you just drop off your requirement.

Comment: The final array you say you want, is a technical impossibility. You can not use the same key `11` twice.

Comment: I'll swap the key and values. Means I need total and group by values.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake. Final question look like this : array(
            '15'=>'11',
            '6'=>'34',
            '9'=>'11',
            );

Comment: Take another sample : Array ( [7] => 19 [2] => 18 [1] => 19 )  I want to convert final array like : Array ( [8] => 19 [2] => 18 )

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I see what you're aiming to do: group together equal values and add their corresponding keys together, but this seems a very weird operation. You're always going to have the risk of two keys being equal and overwriting each other.

Comment: Would it work in your situation if you used a 2d array instead of an object? e.g.`$array = array(array(7,19), array(2,18), array(1,19));`. Then `$array[0][0]` would have value `7`

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array and use each value as the keys in the result array.  Use a null coalescing expression to fallback to zero when a specific value from the input array is encountered for the first time.  As you iterate, simply add the input array's key to the result array's value "sum".

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AEBYV))

```
$array = [
    '7' => '15',
    '20' => '6',
    '11' => '9',
    '14' => '6',
    '4' => '15'
 ];
 
 $result = [];
 foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     $result[$value] = ($result[$value] ?? 0) + $key;
 }
 var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  15 => 11,
  6 => 34,
  9 => 11,
)
```